# jQuery won't recognize button clicks from $(".class").click() or $(".class").on() but works with $(".class").live()

Tags: jquery, html, firebase, button, html-table

Using the deprecated `.live()` method I am able to make this work exactly as I would like however it's not ideal to keep it this way. I've found similar questions suggesting to use the `$(".update").on()` method or to call `$(document).on('click', $('.update'), function()...)` however I wasn't able to make any of the solutions work. The best I was able to do was return the full table but never able to get my snap.key. Any suggestions to make this work with any besides `.live()` would be very much appreciated.

```
  <table id="itemTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody id = "tableBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Firebase call:

```
db.on('child_added', snap => {
    $('#tableBody').append('<tr><td class="up"><span>' + snap.key + '</span></td><td><button type = "button" class="update">Update</button></td></tr>');
});
```

button handler:

```
$(".update").live('click',function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr");   // Find the row
  var $text = $row.find(".up").text(); // Find the text
  console.log($text);
});
```

Comment: My guess is that the `.update` element doesn't exist until after the Firebase call completes, so `click` and `on`, which only attach to items that currently exist on the page, had nothing to attach to. The deprecated `live` works for you because it attaches to the selection "now and in the future", instead of just "now". You can attach `click` or `on` to a parent element, and specify which child selection it should actually listen for. See this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(){...});
```

Note that the 2nd argument to [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) is a selector, whereas you were passing `$('.update')`.